# Array memory allocating override

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

i created a code which will basically create an allocation of an array according to a size of a string,and store a pointer to the allocated array inside a for loop:

```
 int Note;
     int ifd;

     char **pointer[ir];

     for (Note = 0; Note < ir; ++Note) {
         char ** Temp=malloc(Count(' ',Sentences[Note])*sizeof(char *));
                 ifd=StoreArr(Sentences[Note],Temp," ");
                pointer[Note]=&Temp;
                printer(*(pointer[Note]),ifd);

     }
```

char **temp should create a new array each time the function starts,and pointer should store a pointer to the created array.when i print the created arrays,`(printer(pointer[Note]),ifd)). the output is correct:

```
hello
ola
hiya
howdy
eitan
eitanon
eitanya
```

but after exiting the for,and trying to print the first array of strings,i only receive
    eitan
    eitanon
    eitanya

hence,i can persume that the Temp allocation does not create new memory,but simply overrides the existing allocation.
my question is how to solve the problem, in order to allocate new memory to Temp each time and by so allocate room for all arays in Sentences"

Thanks

Comment: i really do not understand the hostility.i am simply trying to learn the bases of the language...i never claimed to be a professional,and i AM reading a book.i do get a bunch of assignment warnings,yet i simply do not understand how to solve those.

Comment: Check realloc man page may help you, [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to figure out what you meant, unless you post the whole code.  However I suspect the following line of code to cause your issue:

```
char **pointer[ir]; //three pointers here
```

When you show the array with the following line.  You are accessing the "local memory" and it works fine.  However once you quit the function, the "local" variables are not longer accessible, thus using them will cause undefined behaviors.

```
printer(*(pointer[Note]),ifd);
```

I would recommend you to change your pointer to something like this:

```
char*** pointer;
```

Bottom line, never return an array declared with []

NB: Give your variables, methods, modules a descriptive name

Cheers !